# HasThis & ExplicitThis calling conventions

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, clr, calling-convention

I come across `HasThis` and `ExplicitThis` calling conventions on [.NET Framework reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/callingconventions.cs,0e671adbca70e090), and thus I begin to wonder:

- When are they set by compiler?
- Are there any examples using this combination of calling conventions (in "real world" managed program)?

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.callingconventions) has described them as:

**ExplicitThis**

> Specifies that the signature is a function-pointer signature, representing a call to an instance or virtual method (not a static method). If `ExplicitThis` is set, `HasThis` must also be set. The first argument passed to the called method is still a `this` pointer, but the type of the first argument is now unknown. Therefore, a token that describes the type (or class) of the `this` pointer is explicitly stored into its metadata signature.

**HasThis**

> Specifies an instance or virtual method (not a static method). At run-time, the called method is passed a pointer to the target object as its first argument (the `this` pointer). The signature stored in metadata does not include the type of this first argument, because the method is known and its owner class can be discovered from metadata.

Here is a [sample program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NRLH08) I wrote to generate a class and constructor using these bits set:

```
const string FileName = "MyDynamicLib.dll";
AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;

AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName(assemblyName: "MyAssembly");
AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = currentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
                                                                      name  : assemblyName,
                                                                      access: AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave
                                                                     );
ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(
                                                                  name          : "MyModule",
                                                                  fileName      : FileName,
                                                                  emitSymbolInfo: true
                                                                 );

TypeBuilder typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType(
                                                   name: "MyClass",
                                                   attr: TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit
                                                  );
ConstructorBuilder constructorBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(
                                                                      attributes       : MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName,
                                                                      callingConvention: CallingConventions.HasThis | CallingConventions.ExplicitThis,
                                                                      parameterTypes   : null
                                                                     );
constructorBuilder.GetILGenerator().Emit(opcode: OpCodes.Ret);
typeBuilder.CreateType();

assemblyBuilder.Save(
                     assemblyFileName      : FileName,
                     portableExecutableKind: PortableExecutableKinds.Required32Bit,
                     imageFileMachine      : ImageFileMachine.I386
                    );
```

---

What is known so far:
It is not possible to change method's calling convention using C# syntax. This is only possible at IL level, also using Reflection emit API.
`HasThis` and `Standard` are the most commonly used, there is no need to explain these.
`VarArgs` bit, on the other hand, it is set for `__arglist` method:

```
static void VariadicMethod(__arglist)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to answer carefully because it's one of the most less clear subject in ECMA but maybe I will be able to shed some light on this.

You can skip to "Back to your question" section to see the final answer.

---

*The answer is a little long because I want to bring a reference so instead of writing my opinion I'll quote. I hope it will be understandable enough. If not, I'll edit the answer with more explanations.*

*The emphases in quotations are mine. Some quotes were cut.*

> The EXPLICITTHIS (0x40) bit **can be set only** in signatures for function pointers: signatures whose
>   MethodDefSig is preceded by FNPTR

From CoreCLR

> EXPLICITTHIS and native call convs are for stand-alone sigs only (for calli)

Function pointers is a way to call unmanaged methods.

> Unmanaged methods can also be called via function pointers.

Function pointers can be called via `calli` instruction

> Method pointer shall store the address of the entry point to a method whose signature
>   is `method-signature-compatible-with` the type of the method pointer. A method can be called by using a method pointer with the `calli`
>   instruction.

More about it

> Correct CIL requires that the function pointer contains the address of a method whose signature
>   is `method-signature compatible-with` that specified by `callsitedescr` and that the arguments
>   correctly correspond to the types of the destination function’s this pointer, if required, and
>   parameters. For the purposes of signature matching, the HASTHIS and EXPLICITTHIS flags are
>   ignored; all other items must be identical in the two signatures.

And

> The `calli` instruction includes a `call site description` that includes information about the native calling
>   convention that should be used to invoke the method. Correct CIL code shall specify a calling convention in the
>   `calli` instruction that matches the calling convention for the method that is being called.

Call site description

> Ccall site
>   description (represented as a metadata token for a `stand-alone call signature`) that provides:
>   • The number of arguments being passed.
>   • The **data type of each argument**.
>   • The order in which they have been placed on the call stack.
>   • The native calling convention to be used

Method-signature-compatible-with mean

> A method signature type T is method-signature compatible-with a method signature type U if
>   and only if:
>   1. For each signature, independently, if the signature is for an instance method it carries
>   the type of this. [Note: This is always true for the signatures of instance method pointers
>   produced by ldvirtftn instruction.
>   2. The calling conventions of T and U shall match exactly, ignoring the distinction
>   between static and instance methods (i.e., the this parameter, if any, is not treated
>   specially).

---

### Back to your question

> - When are they set by compiler?
> - Are there any examples using this combination of calling conventions (in "real world" managed program)?

`ExplicitThis` **can** be using only when calling function pointers via `calli` instruction.

AFAIK the C# compiler **not** generating `calli` instruction, so you will not see any C# code that set this bit.

---

### References

[C# compiler won't generate calli instructions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnfa/2004/06/14/calli-is-not-verifiable/)

[Roslyn source code](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn)

[EXPLICITTHIS and native call convs are for stand-alone sigs only (for calli)](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/03f0b6d5f97a5d65387cad5fd0f60342d3118047/src/utilcode/util.cpp#L2140)

[Signatures under the hood](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42649/%2FArticles%2F42649%2FNET-file-format-Signatures-under-the-hood-Part-1)

[ECMA](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your time. In the meantime, I have figured it has to do something with `calli` / `ldftn`, yes.. I'll post an actual IL example code of this sometime later. It is very unusual and cool.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind about those two flags are [Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods), there's even some information on [how the binding of those methods is done while the code is being compiled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods#binding-extension-methods-at-compile-time).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ok, lets test for that. Quickly writing an extension method, and inspecting its calling conventions using Reflection reveal only `Standard` bit is being set, which makes sense since extension method must be static. `ExplicitThis` requires an instance method, and apparently we can't control this bit using C# syntax. So, on IL level, how can we use it?

Comment: Then maybe explicit interface implementations

Comment: Doesn't seem to be that either. Explicit interface implementation method has `Standard | HasThis` set.

Comment: Sorry, bot no more ideas off the top of my head